# RGB to V (from HSV)

Tags: python, image, opencv, hsv

I am trying to convert an RGB image to its Value component. I cannot use the RGB2HSV function because I have been instructed to convert it without it.
If I am not mistaken, the value of an image is the maximum of the R,G and B components in the pixel; so this is what I have tried to implement.

'''

```
    rgb_copy = self.rgb.copy()

    width, height, other = rgb_copy.shape
    for i in range(0, width-1):
        for j in range(0, height-1):
            # normalize the rgb values
            [r, g, b] = self.rgb[i, j]
            r_norm = r/255.0
            g_norm = g/255.0
            b_norm = b/255.0

            # find the maximum of the three values
            max_value = max(r_norm, g_norm, b_norm)

            rgb_copy[i, j] = (max_value, max_value, max_value)

    cv2.imshow('Value', rgb_copy)
    cv2.waitKey()
```

'''

This unfortunately does not seem to work. It returns just a black image which is not the same as the Value component when I convert it using the inbuilt function.

Can anyone help or see where I have gone wrong?

Comment: You put the normalized values (0..1) back into an RGB image expecting values of 0..255 for each channel.

Comment: is there a reason why you're normalizing?

Comment: You can find the max of the RGB channels much faster and more simply using Numpy, btw. `max = np.max(RGB, axis=-1)`

Comment: *look at* the values in your arrays. if `rgb_copy` is of dtype uint8, and you expect to store floating point numbers that are between 0 and 1, then you'll only see those values there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment above:

Because you attempt to normalize the RGB values by dividing by **255**, I assume your RGB image is a 3 channel, `unsigned char` image (each channel is an `unsigned char` value between **0..255**).

When you clone it with:

```
rgb_copy = self.rgb.copy()
```

You make `rgb_copy` an image of the same type (i.e. 3 channel `unsigned char`).
Then you attempt to populate it with normalized **0..1** `float` values per channel.

Instead you can simply put the max of the RGB channels per pixel.
**Something like:**

```
rgb_copy = self.rgb.copy()
width, height, other = rgb_copy.shape
for i in range(0, width - 1):
    for j in range(0, height - 1):
        # find the maximum of the three values
        max_value = max(self.rgb[i, j])
        rgb_copy[i, j] = (max_value, max_value, max_value)

cv2.imshow('Value', rgb_copy)
cv2.waitKey()
```